# How do I add values to the list of a class type c which in turn contains 2 other classes objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop, c#-4.0

```
Public class A 
{
    public string str1;
    public string str2;
}

Public class B {

    public string str3;
}

Public class C 
{
    B BclassObject;

    //here is a getter; setter to get and set BClassObject;

    A AclassObject;

    //here is a getter; setter to get and set AClassObject;


}
```

Now I am returning data from database which contains columns str1, str2 and str3 in a datatable e.g. `dt`.

```
public List<C> someFunc()
{     

     List<C> listC= new List<C>();

     for(int i=0; i<dt.rows.count; i++)
     {
         C ClassObject = new C();
         listC.Add(new C(){});         
     } 

         return listC;
}
```

Now here is the problem in the last function. I want to assign the value to the `str1`, `str2`, and `str3` which are inside the class `A`, `B`.

How do I do this?

Comment: `ClassObject.AclassObject.str1 = ...` and then `listC.Add(ClassObject);`

Comment: Set the visibility of AclassObject and BclassObject to public or internal as appropriate so that they can be seen from someFunc

Answer (score 1):

You can add a constructor in class C accepting `str1`, `str2` and `str3` and then use these parameters to create the objects of class A and B.

```
Public class A 
{
  public string str1;
  public string str2;
}

Public class B {
 public string str3;
}

Public class C 
{
 B BclassObject;
//here is a getter; setter to get and set BClassObject;
 A AclassObject;
//here is a getter; setter to get and set AClassObject;
 public C(string v1, string v2, string v3){
  AclassObject = new A() {str1=v1,str2=v2};
  BclassObject = new B(){str3 = v3};
 }
}
```